# How to exclude dependencies in java-catalog build.gradle file

Tags: java, gradle

Java catalog references snakeyaml as follows

Java catalog build.gradle declaration
library('snakeyaml', 'org.yaml', 'snakeyaml').version('2.0')

Compilation throws the following error, how to perform the exlcude in the java catalog itself to avoid loading the android.jar

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileTestJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':testCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find snakeyaml-2.0-android.jar (org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/yaml/snakeyaml/2.0/snakeyaml-2.0-android.jar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: It is hard to ascertain what is trying to pull in the snakeyaml-2.0-android.jar - 2 answers have been provided below that may answer your query, but without providing a snippet or more context of what is in your build.gradle file, it will be assumptions from the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define any excludes in a version catalog.

A version catalog is like its name suggests just a catalog of artifacts and their versions from which you can pick from.

Using them is effect-wise equivalent to having the dependency declared literally just not having the benefits of a version catalog.

A declaration in a version catalog can be used in many places.

And things like excludes, attributes, artifact types, and so on are not in the scope of the version catalog, but in the scope of where you use it.

Maybe you also want to have a look at platforms. When asking whether to use a platform or a version catalog, the answer quite often is, use both.

Answer (score 0):

As a product `snakeyaml-2.0-android.jar` does not exist, but `snakeyaml-2.0.jar` does.

Apply an exclusion from the test dependency (in example below - javafaker has been used to illustrate) that is trying to download the `snakeyaml-2.0-android.jar` artifact and request the one that exists:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    testImplementation("com.github.javafaker:javafaker:1.0.2") {
        exclude(group = "org.yaml", module = "snakeyaml")
    }
    testImplementation("org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0")
}
```

Comment: see @Jagroop answer below as well, to apply most relevant solution

Comment: The question was how to do the exclude in the version catalog, so the answer is that it is not possible. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly open `build.gradle` file of java  project and then in the `dependencies` find where `snakeyaml`  is declared.

After that you can exclude groups like this  :

```
dependencies {
    // ... other dependencies
    compile('org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.yaml', module: 'snakeyaml-android'
    }
    // ... other dependencies
}
```

Comment: The question was how to do the exclude in the version catalog, so the answer is that it is not possible. ;-)